# Question about limsup and liminf of slope

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, limsup-and-liminf, slope

Consider the function $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=1 - \sqrt{0.5-x}$ when $x \leq 0.5$ and $g(x)=1$ otherwise.

What is $\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \inf \{\frac{g(0.5+t)-g(0.5)}{t} : 0< \lvert t \rvert <h\}$? I think it is $0$ because the limit from the right hand side is $0$.

And what is $\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \sup \{\frac{g(0.5+t)-g(0.5)}{t} : 0< \lvert t \rvert <h\}$? I think it is $\infty$ because the limit from the left hand side is $0$.

This function looks like this:
[image: plot of the graph]

Comment: This seems correct to me, although I would give the result of the 2nd limit as $+\infty,$ since the possible values of these limits are extended real numbers, that is, elements of the extended real line (i.e. $2$-point compactification of the reals) $\overline{\mathbb R} = \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\} = [-\infty,+\infty].$ The use of $+\infty$ rather than $\infty$ helps the reader recognize that we're not dealing with only a single "point at infinity" set of values (which one often does in complex variables with the Riemann sphere).

Comment: In case it helps, using standard Dini derivate notation (e.g. see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative) and [2](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiniDerivative.html) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/344025/13130)) for your function at $x=0.5$ we have $D_{-}g = D^{-}g = +\infty$ and $D_{+}g = D^{+}g = 0.$ That is, when calculated relative to $x = 0.5$ as the "base point", the inf of the slopes when approaching from the left is $+\infty$ and the sup of the slopes when approaching from the left is $+\infty,$ and similarly (replace $+\infty$ with $0$) from the right.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you very much!